# C/C++ #include formatting best practice

Tags: c++, c, include

In my time with C/C++ I have encountered different ways to handle the file path for the #include directive when including your .h file in your .cpp/.c file.  The Google style guide alludes to using part of the file path in your #include.  That being said, I currently work on a project (albeit a small one) where a nicely laid out Makefile (for G++) and structure was laid out for me when I "inherited" the code.  Namely, there is a directory named /project_name and inside is the Makefile and several sub-directories.  For example, /project_name/inc holds the .h files and /project_name/src holds the .cpp files.  The Makefile is set to look into each sub-directory to compile the source code.

My question is, given the directory structure and the Makefile, what is the "preferred" method for #include.  The two alternatives I am successful with using are listed below.

1. `#include "mycode.h"` - no knowledge of path, assumes structure that I described`
2. `#include "../../project_name/inc/mycode.h"` seems a bit convoluted, but shows the file structure better`

Are there any other options that I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use neither.  Rather, put all your *public* headers in some hierarchy with a single root.  For instance if your project is foo, put all your public headers in, say, `include/foo`, but don't hesitate to group your headers per component:

```
include/foo/io/printer.hh
include/foo/io/reader.hh
include/foo/job/job.hh
include/foo/job/scheduler.hh
```

Then if your code use only `<foo/io/printer.hh>` and so forth, which requires that you pass the proper `-I $(top_srcdir)/include` flags during construction of your project.  This set-up simplifies things if you have to install your headers, as your code and users' code will use the headers exactly the same way.

If in addition you have private headers, use the same structure, but in another hierarchy, for instance:

```
src/io/parser.hh
```

You may, or may not, decide to use `src/foo`.  The advantage of not using `src/foo` is that it is easier to see what are public and private headers.

But never use relative paths.

Answer (score 5):

The first option appears as the less constraining.

If tomorrow the structure of the project directory changes, would you rather modify one makefile or change every single custom `#include` to take the change into account ?

Using the second option will make changes to the directory structure take more time, and the time needed to adapt everything will scale with the project size (whereas with the makefile change, it's constant).

Answer (score 2):

This is a subjective answer; if both work then both are correct, however I prefer to have no knowledge of the source tree within the source code, only in the project settings/Makefile, so for me the first option is best:

```
#include "mycode.h"
```

Comment: Of course, *some* knowledge of the source tree might be beneficial, if it forms part of some convention (e.g. `<boost/xxx.hpp>`, `<tr1/functional>` and so on.

Comment: @juanchopanza I would argue that that isn't directory structure per se, simply a namespace mechanism.  Also you **will** have to use `<lib/header.h>` given most libraries install headers into sub-directories of `/usr/include` and you won't want to explicitly specify every one.

Comment: This namespace mechanism is implemented in terms of a directory structure though. And you can add, say "/usr/include/boost" to your include path. But as long as the paths are not relative, all is fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't forget that `/usr/include` is not part of the source tree.

Answer (score 2):

As trojanfoe says, it is very subjective but still I would go with this style below.

```
#include "mycode.h"
```

If at all there is a need to restructure folders having.cpp/.h files, then the below style becomes fragile and bound to fail. You will be forced to change the .cpp files to provide the correct relative path.

```
#include "../../project_name/inc/mycode.h" //
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that include code structure in #include(i.e. option2) will make code less portable.

i recently met problem when bring a component(that build with jam) to cocoapod to be consumed by IOS. the main problem is that in the code there are following code

```
`#include <impl/xxxxx.h>`
```

when bring into cocoapods, it will not compiled because the path of "impl" is not recoginized and i did not find a setting for that.(i am be wrong, just share what i got now). change to

```
`#include "impl/xxxx.h" `
```

will make this pod compiled succ, but still not be used be client. sicne client code have no idea about the "impl" structure.(if the public interface has no this strucutre include, it will work. but it is not my case)

i end up with removing all this source structure include which becomes to use option 1..

so my point is that.
1) for public header, avoid include source structure.
2) for private header/code, use "private/source/structure/xxxx.h" to easy compile setting.

please share with me if anything.